# exp/imp: Difference between dump created by system user and owner

Tags: oracle, import, export

A question out of interest: If I create a database dump using `exp` as the `system` user, what are the differences compared to when I create the dump with the owner's user (given the owner has the `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` role)? Both dumps are created with the `FULL=Y` option. When I binary diff the dump files, the dumps look fairly identical. Also, the file size actually is identical. Yet, I can only import a dump taken by the `system` as a DBA user:

```
IMP-00013: only a DBA can import a file exported by another DBA
```

Is this a purely a matter of rights management? Or does the `system` user's dump actually contain stuff that the owner's doesn't? I looked around the Oracle documentation, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know the main difference is informaion abour creating users and maintainig grants when you import data. If you create exp file from common user It will contain only user schema objects and you should create user and give him properly grant and so on an so on,   but if you generate exp from user with DBA privileges it will contain metainformaion too (GRANTS and ROLES for example)